# Page redirection depending on the answer chosen using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I probably deserve to get shot by good programmers and great minds alike right now because of how my current code looks like even if I'm a total noob at Objective-C. Anyway, I'm making a logo quiz wherein the questions are in random order, then for each question the choices are also in random order. Anyway, I already have this code below to check where the page should redirect when an answer is selected:

```
- (IBAction)answerA:(UIButton *)sender {
if(imgView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"])
{
    if([btnA.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        [btnA addTarget:self action:@selector(correctView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    else
    {
        [btnA addTarget:self action:@selector(wrongView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}
else if(imgView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"])
{
    if([btnA.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
        [btnA addTarget:self action:@selector(correctView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];            
    }
    else
    {
        [btnA addTarget:self action:@selector(wrongView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}


- (IBAction)answerB:(UIButton *)sender {
    if(imgView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"])
    {
        if([btnB.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            [btnB addTarget:self action:@selector(correctView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        else
        {
            [btnB addTarget:self action:@selector(wrongView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
    }
    else if(imgView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"])
    {
        if([btnB.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
        {
            [btnB addTarget:self action:@selector(correctView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        else
        {
            [btnB addTarget:self action:@selector(wrongView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
    }
}
```

This works but the problem is, you have to click on the button twice for it to go to the corresponding page. I know that the problem is IBAction itself is already an event that triggers once the button is clicked, then I have the code inside the condition statements that would be only triggered if the button is clicked again. My question is, how can I modify this so that if the button is clicked once, it immediately checks for the current question then the correct answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following Code. I am writing one method only, you can write second.

```
- (IBAction)answerA:(UIButton *)sender {
if(imgView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"])
{
  if([btnA.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"1"])
  {
      [self correctView];
  }
  else
  {
      [self wrongView];
  }
}
else if(imgView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"])
{
  if([btnA.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
  {
      [self correctView];
  }
else
  {
      [self wrongView];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I kinda figured out how to fix it and this is pretty much what I did as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the button target/action:

```
[btnA addTarget:self action:@selector(correctView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

which requires another button tap before `correctView` is invoked, why not call the method directly?

```
[self correctView];
```